# How do I push a Mercurial repository to BitBucket over ssh?

Tags: ssh, cron, mercurial

I created a public key for ssh and registered that key with BitBucket. I then attempted to push:

```
$ hg push ssh://jhayward@bitbucket.org/johncharrell/[project name]
pushing to ssh://jhayward@bitbucket.org/johncharrell/[project name
running ssh jhayward@bitbucket.org "hg -R johncharrell/[project name serve --stdio"
remote: Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '[server IP]' to the list of known hosts.
remote: Permission denied (publickey).
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

What do I need to do so that my public key (or some other created for the purpose) will let me do an hg push from the shell or crontab? In BitBucket, I have read and write permissions to the project, but not to my knowledge anything administrative.

Comment: The error `Permission denied (publickey)` basically means your public key is either missing from bitbucket or its somehow invalid. Try making a new `.pub` key with `ssh-keygen` and delete the old one referring to your host machine and register it.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the [correct URL format](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Using+the+SSH+protocol+with+bitbucket)? Normally, it would be: `ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/accountname/reponame/`

Answer (score 0):

To allow pushing, you should upload your public key to bitbucket you can do so with:

- clicking your login icon at the top-right and selecting bitbucket settings
- on the left in the section "SECURITY" select "SSH keys"
- select "Add key" and upload your public key

After that you should be able to upload with any account that has the matching private key installed, even from a cron job.

I also recommend you create your repository first on bitbucket first then use the `ssh` parameter for `hg` provided by BitBucket to pull with mercurial. After that you can just do `hg push` without any parameters.

If you already have a repository, you have to do this in a new directory and copy your initial changes over the repository freshly checked out from BitBucket.

Comment: You can also fix the repository url in local copy's `.hg/hgrc` (section `[paths]`, key `default`).